# how can I stop the seconds on 60 to 0

Tags: javascript, html

Hi im new to javascript and html , I just want to know that how can I stop the third text field(txtS) at 60 to 0. I'm trying to make a clock ,so the seconds need to stop at 60 and minutes should start incrementing.**

I'm only asking is to how to stop seconds at 60

```
<html >
<head>
    <title>clock</title>
    <script language="javascript">
        function fn_sample() {
            document.frm.txtS.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtS.value) + 1;
            var t1 = document.frm.txtS.value;
            if(t1>=60){

                t1 = 0;

            }
            window.setTimeout("fn_sample()", 1000);

        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="txtH" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtM" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtS" value="0" size="2"/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="fn_sample();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: should be using `Date` object for more reliable time. Your approach will lag real time

Comment: You should be using the Date object in order to avoid client's possible lag issues but, in any case, here is a working solution of your case: http://jsfiddle.net/rw2pgqqv/ . Basically, instead of t1 = 0; you have to set the input value to 0.. That's just it. Also, you can use unary operators (like the +) instead of the parseInt, but that's just matter of code review.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `else` after the close brace, to make `setTimeout` depending on previous test.

(For demo, I've reduced timeout to `100` to wait 6 seconds instead of 60;-).
Note for ensuring there in never more than 1 second for a **full loop**, you can't *sleep 1 second* between each operation! Prefer to use : `window.setTimeout("fn_sample()",1000-(new Date()%1000));`. This will work until `fn_sample()` execution time come over 1 second.

```js
        function fn_sample() {
            document.frm.txtS.value = parseInt(document.frm.txtS.value) + 1;
            var t1 = document.frm.txtS.value;
            if(t1>=60){

                document.frm.txtS.value = 0;

            } else
            window.setTimeout("fn_sample()",
                              100-(new Date()%100));

        }
```

```html
    <form name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="txtH" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtM" value="0" size="2"/>
        <input type="text" name="txtS" value="0" size="2"/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="fn_sample();" />
    </form>
```